# Delete cells on submission of Form response edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to delete data in a series of cells when a google form is re-submitted (when Google offers to "edit your response").

Currently, I have this code:

```
// when a cell in column A (F:F) is changed, clear the corresponding cell in column C0-DD
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.columnStart === 12 && e.range.getValue() != 'V01') { 
    e.range.offset(0, 81, 1, 5).clearContent();
  }
}
```

This works perfectly when I edit the row manually (by changing the value in column F to V02). If I try and change to V02 using the Google Form URL then the code doesn't run. I have the trigger set to "on edit"--I've tried "on change" and "on form submission" but none has worked. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to trigger a function to run when a Google Form is submitted is with an installed trigger for the "Form Submit" event.  If you want to handle two different triggers, then you'll need two different functions.

Even though the event object for the Form Submit event has the same `range` property as "On Edit" I wouldn't pass the event object.  I'd get the range, and pass that.

So, create a new function for the form submission, and install the "On Form Submit" trigger.  You'll end up with 3 functions.

```
function runWhenFormSubmitted(e) {//Install with Form Submit trigger
  var rng = e.range;

  clearContentWhenEdit(rng);
}  

function runWhenCellEdited(e) {//Install with On Edit trigger
  var rng = e.range;

  clearContentWhenEdit(rng);
} 

function clearContentWhenEdit(rng) {
  if(rng.columnStart === 12 && rng.getValue() != 'V01') { 
    rng.offset(0,81,1,5).clearContent();
  }
}
```